# php variables get values from jquery variables without post to the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#date").click(function(){
  start = $("#date_start").val();
  end = $("#date_end").val();
});
});
</script>

<input name='date_A' type='text' id='date_start' />
<input name='date_B' type='text' id='date_end' />
<input type="button" id="date" class="button" value="check" />
```

The question is how to get value of "start" and "end" from the jquery to put that in PHP variable without post it first to database?

```
<?php
   $start_date = "";
   $end_date = "";
?>
```

The both variables above need the value of the variable "start" and "end" from jquery above

Comment: you have to use `post` or `get` method for that.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to do. Might be as simple as using a url query string, or you may need ajax

Comment: Since you already know you have to use ajax, what problem are you having?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: I want to use the values from variable "start" and "end" in my php variable  $start_date and $end_date

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#date").click(function(){
  start = $("#date_start").val();
  end = $("#date_end").val();

  $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/your_page_link/',
        data: {start : start, end : end},
        success: function (res) {

        }
    });
});
});
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){ // If you are using same page, then it'll help you to detect ajax request.
   $start_date = $_POST['start'];
   $end_date = $_POST['end'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I need the value without post to the database, how to do?

Comment: What do you mean by without post and how do you want to deal with database here?

Answer (score 0):

I fear you want to read values from jQuery and inject them in PHP *in the same page*, which is impossible.
You have to understand what PHP is first. It generates the page, that is then sent to the browser, that then executes jQuery code. PHP code completely disappeared from the generated page. jQuery has no idea of PHP's presence, they just can't interact this way. You *must* use a GET or POST query in order to send values to a PHP page, back to the server.

You want to read things like this : [Difference between Javascript and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369313/difference-between-javascript-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do.

```
        <form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
        <div id="block">
            <input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate" placeholder="Start date" required/>
            <input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDate" placeholder="End date" required />
            <input type="submit" id="Download" name="Download" value="Download"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and put this code in the same page

```
<?php
        $startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
        $endDate   = $_POST['endDate'];

?>
```