# Javascript, change inner html when body_class() = logged-in

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Attempting to write some Javascript for a Wordpress install.

I have this in my header:

```
<div id="loginWarningRed">
You Must
<a href="#/?edit-account">Log In</a>
To See Pricing
</div>
```

and then

```
.logged-in #loginWarningRed {display:none;}
```

and it's working fine, but I would like to write some Javascript to welcome the user when logged in.

Something like:

```
if (jQuery('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
  document.getElementById(loginWarningRed);innerHTML = "Welcome %USER%";
}
```

However, when I put this snippet in my custom js text-area, nothing happens. I have no error message in the console.

Also, for the record, I have changed css to `/*.logged-in {display:none;}*/`.

Comment: there's a typo: `;innerHTML`

Comment: When are you adding the 'logged-in' class to the body?

Comment: @d79 what is the typo? you typed the same as I had...

Comment: @Carlouuus, the class logged-in gets added to the body automatically when the user is logged into their account. I believe its called `body_class()`

Comment: @RobBenz sorry, it should be `.innerHTML`

Comment: <body <?php body_class($class); ?>>

Comment: @d79 when i edited code to read `if ($('div#loginWarningRed').hasClass('logged-in') ){
      document.getElementById(loginWarningRed);.innerHTML = "Welcome %USER%"; }`

I get the console error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use JavaScript for this, but PHP, editing the header template containing `<div id="loginWarningRed">`:

```
<div id="loginWarningRed">

    <?php if( is_user_logged_in() ): $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>

        Welcome <?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>

    <?php else: ?>

        You Must
        <a href="#/?edit-account">Log In</a>
        To See Pricing

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, would you mind explaining why I should be using php instead of javascript... just a sentence or two please, thank you very much.

Comment: well one reason is that javascript is client side (that is works on the user browser) and php is server side: in your case you need to retrieve something from the server (the user infos), hence the php. for other reasons please take a look at [this anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6369454/3236352).

Comment: Thanks again, I want to modify the `if` to change `user_login` to `display_name` if `display_name` exists. that way it wont say "Welcome Jsmith1234" it will say "Welcome John Smith"

Comment: you can use `$current_user->display_name`, so you let the user decide which name to display (setting on user profile), otherwise use `$current_user->user_firstname . ' ' . $current_user->user_lastname`. for more info: [wp_get_current_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are already using jQuery, you can try this:

```
$('div#loginWarningRed').empty().text('Welcome %USER%')
```

Comment: thanks, but this didn't work, also the text needs to change for a user who is logged-in vs a user who is not logged-in, Is this suppose to be part of an `if` statement?