# Display a collection of images in my webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, web

This is a noob question but I'm a little confused. The thing is that I'm making a webpage which has a a lot of images that must be shown (it is a shop's website). My doubt is that I'm not sure about if I have to load this "collection" of pictures using php or javascript. 
I know php is executed on the server side and javascript on the client's but I don't fully understand the difference.
Thank you all.

Comment: PHP is probably the best idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Javascript and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369313/difference-between-javascript-and-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely a duplicated question, however I wanted to share [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/picture-showcase-php-html/) with you, it is how to do that step by step on PHP.

In a nutshell using PHP you can create an array of image names like this:

```
$images = array("img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.jpg", "img4.jpg", "img5.gif");
```

And then cycle through all the array printing them like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  echo "<img src='" . $images[$i] ."' /><br>";
}
```

Hope it helps, good luck!