# How do i append the PHP code to the Javascript append function under <script> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

My Script file is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".select2").select2();
          var MaxInputs       = 50; //maximum input boxes allowed
          var InputsWrapper   = $("#overall_wrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
          var AddButton       = $("#AddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID
          var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
          var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added      
          $(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
          {
           if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
           {
           FieldCount++; //text box added increment
           //add input box
           $(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="repeat_element" id="row_'+FieldCount+'"><div class="col-sm-1" id="row1_'+FieldCount+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="s_no[]" value="'+FieldCount+'"  /></div><div class="col-sm-2" id="row1_'+FieldCount+'"><select class="form-control select2" name="part_no[]" id="part_no" onchange="choose_parts(this.value);" required><option value="">Please Select</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-3" id="row1_'+FieldCount+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="part_desc[]" value=""  /></div><div class="col-sm-1" id="row1_'+FieldCount+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="part_mrp[]" value=""  /></div><div class="col-sm-1" id="row1_'+FieldCount+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="req_qty[]" value=""  /></div><div class="col-sm-1" id="row1_'+FieldCount+'"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="instock[]" value=""  /></div><div class="col-sm-2" id="row1_'+FieldCount+'"><select class="form-control" name="billing_type[]"><option value="Cash">Cash</option><option value="Credit">Credit</option></select></div><div class="col-sm-1" id="row1_'+FieldCount+'"><div onclick="hiding('+FieldCount+')" class="removeclass"><div class="btn btn-danger" id="AddMoreFileBox"><i class=" fa fa-minus-circle" title="Delete"></i> </div></div></div>');
                    $(".select2").select2();  // Reinitialize the select2 again when the div is appended
                    x++; //text box increment
                    }
                    return false;
                    });

        });
</script>
```

And i have a page where i call this Add button jquery and i get the second row fine but i am unable to call the PHP functions like `foreach`,`if` into the append script.

[image]

My doubt is that when i click on the plus sybmol i have called the select2 JS and it comes fine but i need to call the PHP function into it for looping of `option value` in the `<select>`.

I need to generate dynamic options in this selected tag under my JS

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="part_no[]" id="part_no" onchange="choose_parts(this.value);" required><option value="">Please Select</option></select>
```

My PHP function for getting the

```
function getAllActiveSpare($id)
{
    $query="";
    $conn=connectToDB();
    if(func_num_args()==1)
    {
     $query="SELECT * FROM `spare` WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `status`='1' AND `delete_status`='0'";
    }
    else
    {
    $query="SELECT * FROM `spare` WHERE `delete_status`='0' AND `status`='1' ORDER BY `id` DESC ";
    }
    $results = $conn->query($query);
    $counts = $results->num_rows;
    if($counts==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $rows=[];
        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }   
}
```

> I need to append this part alone in the JS Select TAG under append function.

```
<?php $parts_number = getAllActiveSpare();                      
if($parts_number==false)
{
?>
<option value="">No Parts Created Yet</option>
<?php  
}
else
{
?>
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<?php  
foreach ($parts_number as $key => $single_parts) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $single_parts['ref_part_no']; ?>"><?php echo $single_parts['ref_part_no']; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>                             
</select>
```

This above things alone i have tried. Can anyone help me with this . I was struck up for the past two Days.

Comment: Could it be that you completely miss the point that javascript works client side and php works server side? You need to perform an ajax call for that and post the values to the server side to be able to use php.

Comment: @arkascha. Thanks for the reply. But my question is how do i append that PHP function from JS using the append function alone. I am getting all the post values to be correct but i am unable to use the PHP functions inside it. Can u explainon that part alone..

Comment: Yes its good if you using AJAX from your end.

Comment: You did not understand a word of what I wrote above. There is absolutely no sense in "appending php to a js script or function". You cannot use php on the client side. Period. (At least not unless you have a very special, academic setup to prove something)

Comment: @arkascha. Hmm okie i understand. How should i change the functions now inorder to solve the problem

Comment: As already said: make an AJAX call to post the values from Javascript to the server, so to php. Then process the posted values, output whatever you want, so send it back. Then you can use the payload the AJAX call receives to append() it however and wherever you want.

Comment: _Or_ you simply implement your loop in javascript instead of php :-)

Comment: @arkascha. As i run short of time only 1 hour remains to complete the project. It is better that i do it in js itself. How can i implement it... Urgent help needed.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not our issue that you work under such horrible terms. And we certainly are not here to help you with that issue. Sorry. We are here to give advice for specific issues you run into. We are not here to do your work for you.

Comment: You need to create a separate php page and send get/post request with the parameters. Javascript is loaded after the complete execution of PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not understand the difference between PHP and JavaScript, or the difference between the server and client side.

[Difference between Javascript and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369313/difference-between-javascript-and-php)

To solve your problem, you probably need to use Ajax.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/851885

Comment: This is not an answer, it should have been a comment.

Comment: @arkascha Well Im not going to write his application for him when he doesn't understand the fundamentals of what he's doing.

Comment: Absolutely correct. You should not. That is not the issue here. Did you even bother to understand _what_ I said above?

Comment: @arkascha You seem quite angry about something. Are you ok?

Comment: Actually I am quite relaxed and enjoy my life. I just pointed out something I think is somewhat important. Answers should answer a question. Comments are used to comment a question. There is a difference. That's all. Why or how does this suggest that I might be "angry"?!?