# How to pass a JavaScript variable in onClick function

Tags: javascript, onclick

Here is my code, I wanna get the element info in the click function like my annotation says.

```
for(var i = 0, len = json.length; i < length; i++) {
  var curid = json['success'][i]['courier_id'];
  var curname = json['success'][i]['courier_name'];
  document.getElementById("gsid").value=curname;                    
  var tr="<tr>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

  //here is where i want to use onclick function with curid and curname 
  var td1="<td>"+"<input type='radio' name='as' value='json['success'][i]['courier_id']' id='curiid' onclick='courierselect(<?php echo $shyam='\'+curname+\''; ?>);'/>"+"</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  var td2="<td id='curnname'>"+json['success'][i]['courier_name']+"</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  var td3="<td>"+json['success'][i]['country_charge']+"</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  var td4="<td>"+json['success'][i]['estimate_delivery_time']+"</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  var td5="<td>"+json['success'][i]['tracking_available']+"</td></tr>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  $("#results").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4+td5); 
}
```

Comment: maybe you can try `onclick='courierselect(<?php echo $shyam='\'+this,curname+\''; ?>);'`. I don't know `php`, but use `this` in `onclick` will valid.

Comment: it showing (SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script ) error@tomlsion

Comment: I am new in `php`, you could have try my changed code.

Comment: yes i try this but it showing error which i mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three problems on your code

- `... value='json['success'][i]['courier_id']' ...`

You didn't concact the variable with the string

- `... courierselect(<?php echo $shyam='\'+curname+\''; ?>) ...`

  1. `echo $shyam='\'+curname+\'';` you can't set a PHP variable with a JS value. [Understand why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369313/difference-between-javascript-and-php)
  2. You `echo` a string value, so you have to add some quotes around `curname`

---

```
for(var i = 0, len = json.length; i < length; i++) {
  var curid = json['success'][i]['courier_id'];
  var curname = json['success'][i]['courier_name'];
  document.getElementById("gsid").value = curname;

  $("#results").append('<tr>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  $("#results").append('<td><input type="radio" name="as" value="' + curid + '" id="curiid" onclick="courierselect(\'' + curname + '\');"/></td>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  $("#results").append('<td id="curnname">' + curname + '</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  $("#results").append('<td>' + json['success'][i]['country_charge'] + '</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  $("#results").append('<td>' + json['success'][i]['estimate_delivery_time'] + '</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  $("#results").append('<td>' + json['success'][i]['tracking_available'] + '</td></tr>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
```

Comment: Thanx you sir your code is working :) last one if i want to pass multiple variable than can i do this {courierselect(\'' + curname + '\',\'' + curid+ '\')}

Comment: Yes, you can : `onclick="courierselect(\'' + curname + '\',\'' + curid+ '\');`. If `curid` is _int_, the quotes are not necessary : `onclick="courierselect(\'' + curname + '\', curid);`