# set session in codeigniter using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

So I want to store the session in jquery. `export_type` is storing all the ids which is checked via checkbox I want to store all those ids in the session. Following is my code ,  But I have **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token** error. Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

```
$("#export").click(function () {
    var id = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
        id[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    var export_type = id;
    var set_session = "<?php $this->session->set_userdata('export_type', export_type); ?>";
    export_php();
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369313/difference-between-javascript-and-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript cannot read PHP. What you will have to do is to have your script make a separate request to a CodeIgniter controller.

Javascript:

```
$.get("export/set_session/" + export_type, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

PHP (application/controllers/Export.php):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Export extends CI_Controller {

    public function set_session($export_type)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('export_type', $export_type);
        echo 'Session set!';
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your above javascript  code lies in the view file as inline javascript inside a script tag then it is should be fine but, if this code is inside in a different javascript file then it will not work.