# Can't call JavaScript function from PHP using a string as a parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I am using a PHP script to get data from a MySQL server. Once I get that data, I'm looping through it (still in PHP) and using it to output a series of datasets each with their own button

```
        $returnString = '<form action="/iOS/action_page.php" method="post">';
        
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
            $echoString = '<h2>Study Title: '. $row['title'] . '</h2>';
            
            $echoString .= '<h3>Study Nickname: ' . $row['nickname'] .'</h3>';
            
            $echoString .= '<button type="button" id="login-button" Onclick="setUrl(' . rawurlencode($row['title']) . ')"> View Tasks </button>';
                            
            echo $echoString;
        }
```

(The "title" of the row is a string that may or may not have spaces and such, like "Hello%20World")

The 'setUrl' function sits outside of the PHP brackets and just tries to move to a new page:

```
        <script>
          function setUrl(tableTitle) {
              window.location.href = "https://exampleWebsite.com/PHPPage.php?id=".concat(tableTitle);
          };

       </script>
```

But every time I try to click a button, I get this error popping up in the console:

```
SyntaxError: No identifiers allowed directly after numeric literal
```

The only way I can get it to work is by passing in an Integer rather than a string, but that doesn't work for my use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Javascript and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369313/difference-between-javascript-and-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing *three different languages* on a single line of code drastically increases the chances of string quoting errors.  Consider what this line of code outputs:

```
$echoString .= '<button type="button" id="login-button" Onclick="setUrl(' . rawurlencode($row['title']) . ')"> View Tasks </button>';
```

If the "title" value is a string, the resulting button is:

```
<button type="button" id="login-button" Onclick="setUrl(some string)"> View Tasks </button>
```

Which means the JavaScript you're trying to execute is:

```
setUrl(some string)
```

Which is invalid because strings need to have quotes around them.

The quickest approach is to simply add those quotes:

```
$echoString .= '<button type="button" id="login-button" Onclick="setUrl(\'' . rawurlencode($row['title']) . '\')"> View Tasks </button>';
```

A more sustainable solution would be to separate your JavaScript from your HTML entirely.  Output just the button with the "title" as a data attribute:

```
$echoString .= '<button type="button" id="login-button" data-title="' . rawurlencode($row['title']) . '"> View Tasks </button>';
```

Then in separate JavaScript (either on the page itself or linked from a `.js` file), bind the click handler:

```
document.querySelector('#login-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  setUrl(this.getAttribute('data-title'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I learned mainly how to code in Swift, so the thought of putting 3 different languages on the same line is crazy to me! But I appreciate it! I knew I had to add quotes somewhere, I just didn't know where.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the argument in the JavaScript.

```
$echoString .= '<button type="button" id="login-button" onclick="setUrl(\'' . rawurlencode($row['title']) . '\')"> View Tasks </button>';
```